# Split line into multiple line

Tags: geometry, line

I have a one line. For this line I have start and end point. Now I want to split this line into multiple lines or number of points. How to do that?

The line looks likes below ..

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a programming question. Could you provide some specifics of the technology you are using here?

Comment: Prolly procedurale art.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python solution:

```
def split(start, end, segments):
    x_delta = (end[0] - start[0]) / float(segments)
    y_delta = (end[1] - start[1]) / float(segments)
    points = []
    for i in range(1, segments):
        points.append([start[0] + i * x_delta, start[1] + i * y_delta])
    return [start] + points + [end]

print split([-10, 20], [20, 75], 5)
```

Output:

```
[[-10, 20], [-4.0, 31.0], [2.0, 42.0], [8.0, 53.0], [14.0, 64.0], [20, 75]]
```

Comment: Can you please post this answer in java? I am using java code.

Comment: I'm rusty on Java and I don't have my machine set up to code in Java right now. Do you know how to program in Java? Python is a high-level, easily readable language. Take a few minutes to try to understand this code and then try to translate it to Java. Hint: take the difference between the x values of your two points and divide that value by the number of segments you want. This quotient is your "x_delta". To get the x value of each intermediate point, add the "x_delta" to the previous point. Do the same for y.

Comment: Thanx for your explanation. is it general solution? means this can be working for any start and point?

Comment: Yes, it will. Just make sure that when calculating your deltas, you do "ending_point - starting_point", or else your intermediate points will go in the opposite direction. Depending on your application, you might need to handle the cases where "segments" is less than 2. If it's 1, then you aren't splitting the line. If it's 0, well, that just doesn't make sense to have a line with 0 segments.